How to fill 'knowledge of major field' whilst applying for a PhD scholarship
I am currently applying for a PhD scholarship and one of the required fields is knowledge of major field.
I have searched online and can't find what this means. I tried to fill in my educational background but I'm guessing it's more than this because there's another field for that. I also tried adding my relevant work experience and research but they also have their respective fields on the application site.
I don't know if I'm missing something and would really love the help of this community in understanding what this means.
Asking the university directly may not help as previous emails are yet to be replied for months.

Could this not just mean your major?

@Sursula I'll try that... Maybe I should state how my major qualifies me for the research project?

This situation strikes me as strange. The only place where I've been asked to fill out "knowledge of major field" is on the forms that I (as a professor) had to fill out when recommending students for graduate programs.
